# icon text to the right

Tags: windows, windows-8, icons

My wife's Windows 8 and now Windows 8.1 computer has the icon text on the desktop to the right of the icons instead of below it. The icons and text below it actually look like the "detailed" full icon view in Windows 8 folders.

Altogether, it's like there's a "space" that the text resides in, to the right of the icon, that's twice the size of the icon itself. It's very annoying as all her icons are almost impossible to read now, and they're super sized, which causes her to run out of space much quicker.

How do you get this to revert back to the normal behavior of the icon text being below the icon, with normal size icons? I've looked everywhere, google, registry, group policy, control panel, even accessibility options and can't seem to find it.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?  Does it do it in [Safe Mode](http://www.howtogeek.com/107511/how-to-boot-into-safe-mode-on-windows-8-the-easy-way/)?

Comment: added screenshot, and yes, it happens in safe mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only source I could find was this one, which advised using a freeware tool called D-Color to do it. How exactly that software does it I don't know.

To change the icon size, right click an empty part of the desktop, point to `View`, and then click `Medium icons`.

Source: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/display-desktop-icons-text-side-windows-7

Comment: This worked, but only if I kept D-Color installed the entire time, marking it as the answer, because the issue disappeared when upgrading to Windows 10, and I never found any other answer.